# Can you determine from the history of x,y coordinates of the mover whether he's employing the levy walk?

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk

I have a movement model that is creating traces much like the traces of a Levy walk. I would like to statistically justify that the movement model is indeed a levy model. For that, I believe I need to show that it follows a power law distribution. Can I use the history of x,y coordinates to check if the movement is a levy walk/flight? If so, how?
[image: Example trace from the model]

Answer (score 0):

The important part is the step *length*; if you can find those from the history of coordinates, then the rest falls into place: to detect a power law distribution you can take a power law regression, which is essentially taking, for each index and matching value $k$, $x_k$, their logarithms $\log(k)$ and $\log(x_k)$, and taking a linear regression through those values.  A power-law distribution will correlate well in this situation.

Comment: Can you point me to some material that can help me with that? What I understand is that for
'y = ax^b'
power law holds if
log(f(x)) = log(x)
is a straight line. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Also, if I use the coordinates according to [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVVARi_9g74) ,  The plot that I get, does that prove teh existence of a power law?

Comment: That's right.  Looks like that video shows you how it's done.  One thing though: "prove", in statistics, is a lot harder than it might sound; in general you will have evidence toward your conclusion, but *proof* isn't going to come from any one dataset, or any million.

Comment: thank you. Also, using the approach in the video, do I still need to determine the step length? Can you share any procedure on how that can be done? I've found some material on Hawth analysis tool but not sure if that can work in my scenario.

Comment: The step length is merely the magnitude of each line in your path.  It is the thing you care about, and the only thing a levy flight cares about.